# Microsoft Edge clean session when running selenium tests

Tags: selenium

I'm using Microsoft Edge 13. How do I ensure a clean session whenever Microsoft Edge browser starts and runs a test suite? I'm trying to run selenium tests using the Microsoft Edge driver, and I am not able to clear cookies/cache on browser close as that option is not available for Microsoft Edge 13.

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered that issue myself today and the only way I got it to work was to check "Always clear this when I close the browser" in Edge settings (and select the things that you want to clear).

With that setting you will have clean session on each new driver initialization :)

[image]